# Delay Boostrap 3 carousel slide event until animation completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Using the Boostrap 3 carousel slide event,

```
$carousel.bind('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    // call function here
});
```

how can I delay the actual sliding event until after a function has completed? I want to animate out the content of the current slide before it transitions to the next slide, but can't figure out how the slide event can be delayed.

Comment: have you tried setTimeout ? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_settimeout

Comment: and here is http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-options carousel interval (delay)

Comment: The interval option is for controlling the time a slide remains visible before sliding, not the duration of the actual slide event, so I don't think that could help. setTimeout() will delay the function to be called on the slide event, but not the actual slide event, unless I'm not using it correctly.